# Google Http Java Client parsing to enum

Tags: java, json

So, I'm aware that you can parse json values into enums using [`@Value`](http://javadoc.google-http-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/1.13.1-beta/com/google/api/client/util/Value.html)annotation, but what is the behavior if the value in the json does not match any values annotated with `@Value`. For example, say an api decides to add a new type that your client doesn't know about. Does its value get set to null, or is there an exception? Is there a way to set an enum value as the default catch all value?

Comment: Why not use something like https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/? It's all already there. Or if you like to save and read back objects you could use https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/ no need to write your own parser?

Comment: Their javadoc is pretty barebones, but it seems to suggest that an enum value named `NOT_A_VALUE` is used as a catch-all. What happens if you have one of those defined?

Answer (score 2):

According to [this Google groups post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-http-java-client/HE4aepDr8g0), you will get `NullPointerException`.

### Edit

Referenced content:

> I have an object called Job with a enum field statusCode that holds an
>   API.  That enum is correctly annotated with @Value, so long as the
>   enum handles all possible values that might come back in the
>   status_code field, json parsing works just fine.
>
> ```
> public static class Job {
>
>     @Key("status_code")
>     public JobStatus statusCode;
> }
>
> public enum JobStatus {
>
>     @Value("starting")
>     STARTING
> }
> ```
>
> However, if an unknown value comes back in that field, then I get a
>
> ```
> NullPointerException:
> java.lang.NullPointerException
>   at com.google.api.client.util.Data.parsePrimitiveValue(Data.java:445)
>   at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parseValue(JsonParser.java:795)
>   at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:438)
>   at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parseValue(JsonParser.java:745)
>   at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:358)
>   at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:331)
>   at com.google.api.client.json.JsonObjectParser.parseAndClose(JsonObjectParser.java:87)
>   at com.google.api.client.json.JsonObjectParser.parseAndClose(JsonObjectParser.java:81)
>   at com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponse.parseAs(HttpResponse.java:459)
> ```
>
> I would like this code to be robust such that if an unknown value
>   comes back it will be treated as null rather than throwing an
>   exception and not returning the Job object.  Is there any way to do
>   this?

Comment: Please include more detail into the answer. If the linked page gets removed or becomes inaccessible, this link-only answer will become irrelevant.